# Why does parameter pack expansion work differently with different C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, parameters

Parameter pack expansion is reversed by the VS2015 compiler.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template <typename... T>
void f_Swallow(T &&...)
{
}

template <typename... T>
std::vector<int> f(T ...arg)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    f_Swallow
    (
        [&]()
        {

            result.push_back(arg);
            return true;
        }
        ()...
    ) ;
    return result;
}


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto vec = f(1,2,3,4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
}
```

When I run this code in XCode (clang-700.1.81), I get this result:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But the same code run in VS2015 produces this output:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Why are the parameter packs expanded differently depending on the compiler? Is there a way to fix it without checking the platform and compiler version? 
Doesn't the standard guarantee anything about expansion order?

Comment: Isn't this just unspecified evaluation order? (side note: typically in `swallow` idiom array brace initializer is used just to avoid this problem)

Comment: @milleniumbug, you are correct. And you should post that as an answer (albeit with some more explaining).

Comment: The correct way to do this is with an initializer list, which guarantees the order of construction: `auto dummy = {(result.push_back(arg), 0)...};` [Demo](http://rextester.com/XHIYH83588)

Comment: Why your code fails with gcc: https://goo.gl/uTtFiC

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not the order of parameter pack expansion which is different, it's the order of function argument evaluation.

```
f_Swallow
(
    [&]()
    {

        result.push_back(arg);
        return true;
    }
    ()...
) ;
```

For sake of brevity, lets just give that lambda the name `funcN` where `N` is the parameter number. Given four arguments, the parameter pack will be expanded *by any conforming compiler* into this:

```
f_Swallow(func1(), func2(), func3, func4()) ;
```

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified in C++. The compiler could evaluate them in-order (like your version of Clang), in reverse order (like your version of MSVC), or in any order it likes. You cannot count on the evaluation order.

To get what you want, you could put the expressions into a context in which the order of evaluation is specified. For example:

```
template <typename... T>
std::vector<int> f(T ...arg)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> { (result.push_back(arg), 0)... };
    return result;
}
```

---

In C++17, you'll be able to do the following with [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename... T>
std::vector<int> f(T ...arg)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    (result.push_back(arg), ...);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I figured that it could be also written just like this:

```
template <typename... T>
std::vector<int> f(T ...arg)
{
    std::vector<int> result{ arg... };
    return result;
}
```

No need to create dummy std::initializer_list

Comment: Haha, yes, that's the best solution for the case when you just want to create a `std::vector` from your parameters.

Comment: Out of interest, what is useful about this, _vs._ `vector`'s own `initializer_list` constructor, which it calls anyway? Currently it looks to me like all it does is waste lines of text, but I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: In my case, the function was used in like this `auto vec = f();` in many places, so it was easier to fix the function, rather changing all calls.